# Laravel 8 shows Array to string conversion during insert into database

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a script that is supposed to add to the database in a `foreach` loop,
but the challenge I am facing is that it gives me `Array to string conversion error`:

```php
$student_data = [];

foreach ($student_average as $avg) {
    $student_data[] = $avg[0];

    $stream_query = Grade::find($avg[0]->class_id);
    $stream = $stream_query->stream;

    $student_number = json_encode($avg[0]->student_id, true);
    $assessement = json_encode($assessement_id, true);
    $grade_id = json_encode($avg[0]->class_id, true);
    $stream_id = json_encode($stream, true);
    $number_of_passed_subjects = json_encode($number_of_passed_subjects, true);
    $passing_subject_status = json_encode($passing_subject_status_query, true);
    $term_id = json_encode(1);
     
    $pr_data = AssessementProgressReport::where('student_id', $avg[0]->student_id)
        ->where('assessement_id',$assessement_id)
        ->where('student_average',$avg[0]->average_mark)
        ->exists();

    if($pr_data){

    }else{
        $student_progress_report = AssessementProgressReport::create([
            'student_id' => $student_number,
            'assessement_id' => $assessement,
            'grade_id' => $grade_id,
            'stream_id' => $stream_id,
            'number_of_passed_subjects' => $number_of_passed_subjects,
            'passing_subject_status' => $passing_subject_status_query,
            'term_id' => $term_id,
        ]);
    }
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Please, show the exact error and which line is happening. Also, you have a lot of `json_encode` that is not a good sign, something seems off if you have so many when storing data... You are also iterating `$student_average` as `$avg` but you are doing `$avg[0]` (getting the first element), so what is `$student_average` that is already not working for you as `$avg` and you have to do `$avg[0]` ? That is another really bad sign that you are doing something wrong...

Comment: @matiaslauriti the error is happing within the create:: method.

Comment: @Shuast paste the exact error that is thrown. It'll also help a sample dump of the data you are passing to the function.